# Problem with Google Maps android

Tags: android, maps

I made an application which displays me the map by taking GPS lat and long. Now when I run that application on my mobile or emulator it works fine. But when I sign the application and install that apk on some other mobile it does not display the Map. It just show me the overlay Item.

Friends I'm stuffed please help

I have MapsActivity Class and Overlay Item Class and I took help from here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the page you link to, there are two important points you should consider:

> This tutorial requires that you have
>   the external Google Maps library
>   installed in your SDK environment.
>
> For the purpose of this tutorial, you
>   should register with the SDK debug
>   certificate, which will only be valid
>   while your application is signed with
>   the debug key (once you sign with your
>   private key, you will need a new API
>   key)

Now, while the first talks about the SDK environment, it's also likely that you should ensure the Google APIs are present on the target device. I'll admit that this is likely to already be the case however.

What I think is more likely to be the problem is the second point - Once you sign the APK with your release key, you need a different Google maps API key. This, I suspect, is the problem.

Comment: Yes Friend i m Sure the Second Point is the problem. Now pLease can u guide me how to sign my application with release key. i have my release key with me. It is my first Application in Google Maps.

Comment: When you export a signed APK from Eclipse, it's already signed with your release key so you should be OK so far as signing the APK is concerned, but you do need a new maps API key that corresponds to your release key - Google has step-by-step instructions here: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Answer (score 4):

You should sign your application with release key because emulator use debug key.

Comment: See http://code.google.com/intl/da-DK/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html on how to obtain a maps api key for your signed app

Comment: I doubt it's a signing issue as the app installs and runs on the target device.

Comment: It is a signing issue. The Google maps API key is connected to the key which is used to sign the application. It seems that he used Google maps API key which is generated with the debug key.